# Creating dynamic map scale in FME

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, fme-form, mapping, data-driven-pages

Is there a way to generate a dynamic map scale for my dataset so that when I create a PDF map, I can create several PDFs at different scales (based on the size of the feature) at once?

For example, when I take my dataset from FME and view it in ArcMap, I could then use the Data Driven Pages option to run though and scale my data automatically.

My input dataset is a geodatabase feature dataset with polygons that I want to iterate through. I need to zoom on every single feature (each may require a different scale) and generate a PDF for each.

Comment: You can create bounding boxes for each of your features extent - There is a good guide here https://community.safe.com/s/article/creating-pdf-cartographic-output

Comment: What did you use FME for ? If your data are in a geodatabase and you are using ArcMap to visualise it the data driven pages seem to do exactly what you want. Could you detail more your exact need and problem ?

Comment: I would like to create a new attribute field for my data, say "Scale", which can automatically determine which scale the data driven page should use. For example, I want to use specific scale intervals (of 2500) so it would be useful if I can use FME to determine which scale range the data lies in, and then give it an attribute value (rounded to the most appropriate scale interval) to then use in the DDP.

Comment: The data driven page has an option to round scale, if you set the rounding value to 2500 it will display your feature to the nearest 2500 increment scale that fit it. This could be close to what you need....

Comment: Thanks I appreciate that - was just hoping to find out if there was an FME means of automating an additional step so that I could use this as a scale attribute. Particularly as I may not always want 2500 increments, but instead scales of 500, 1250, 2500, 5000 etc.

Comment: It sounds like you could use the BoundingBoxReplacer (or Accumulator) transformer to create the extents of the data, and then use that box to calculate what scale fits on your page? You'll get an attribute in the output to tell you how long each side is, and then you can figure out the scale to use to fit it on the required paper size. The MapFormatter transformer on the FME Hub does a similar thing, but it scales your data to a particular scale for a particular paper size. You sort of want a variation on that I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this using the BoundsExtractor to extract the co-ordinates (max/min) of my features. I then created X and Y extents (XExtent = xmax - xmin; YExtent = ymax - ymin). I then used a series of TestFilters and AttributeManagers to assign a map scale based on value ranges of the X and Y extent (for example, If XExtent > YExent AND XExtent < 220, MapScale = 1250).